# pt-kill match against query ID/digest?

Tags: linux, percona

There's a specific large query that gets run and I'd like pt-kill to match based on the query ID/digest ideally.

I don't see a way to do that though in the docs. I also tried to match by the query fingerprint but that wasn't working either.

Can either be matched with pt-kill?